# Getting duration of all mp3 files inside catalog.

Tags: python, mp3, duration

For first: I am total beginner with Python.

I just need to automate adding mp3 files to my shop. All of them are inside one catalog. Filename will be a Product Name, and file duration will be a Description of that product.

I've wrote a simple Python script which reading all mp3 filenames from catalog and just printing them out. 
It looks like this:

```
import os
filenames = next(os.walk("./", topdown=True))[2]
i = 0
while i < len(filenames):
    print(filenames[i].replace(".mp3", ""))
    i += 1
```

It works great but now I need to read duration of all *.mp3 files from the same catalog.

I found library called [Mutagen](https://github.com/quodlibet/mutagen).
I can easily get duration of one file using this library but I can't read duration of files from whole catalog.

Code for reading length of single mp3 file:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3("example.mp3")
print audio.info.length
```

Do you have any idea on how to read duration of all *.mp3 files inside one catalog and print them out?

Comment: I don't know that library. It _might_ provide a function that can scan the info of a list of files, or a directory of files, but you will probably have to loop over the files yourself and get the durations one by one.

Comment: `next(os.walk("./", topdown=True))[2]` is a bit convoluted - it won't get all files from all subdirs, only the first one. You should do a full `for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):`.

Comment: … or, if you really just do want the files in one subdirectory, just `os.scandir` that subdirectory instead of using `os.walk`.

Comment: @nosklo I didn't wanted to load files from subdirectories.  Also, that code was my first 5 mins with Python, haha :) Anyway thank you for advice guys!

Comment: @KTW if you don't want to load subdirectories then `os.walk()` is not a good match - its entire point is to "walk" in a directory structure. Use `os.scandir()` instead (or `os.listdir()` if you want the code to run on python 3.4 or below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
filenames = next(os.walk("./", topdown=True))[2]
for filename in filenames:
    audio = MP3(filename)
    print audio.info.length
    print(filename.replace(".mp3", ""))
```

Comment: After a few adjustments it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even I wanted a similar problem. After looking up at various sites I got an answer. Refer my code below. If you are using windows OS then remember to write an **r** before your path directory.

```
import os
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\*#*")// path of the directory 
print("Directory changed") 
obj = os.scandir() 
def convert(seconds):
    hours = seconds // 3600
    seconds %= 3600
    mins = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return(hours, mins, seconds)
for entry in obj : 
    if entry.is_dir() or entry.is_file(): 
        audio = MP3(entry)
        hours, mins, seconds = convert(audio.info.length)
        print(str(int(hours)) + ":" + str(int(mins)) + ":" + str(int(seconds)))
        print(entry.name) // for audio file name
obj.close()
```

I had used the following links for reference.

https://www.codespeedy.com/find-the-duration-of-an-mp3-file-in-python-mutagen/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-scandir-method/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-chdir-method/